# BeautifulSoup не парсит блок внутри тега span

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Алгоритм парсит нужный элемент span, но не может спарсить его содержимое.

```
...for pricelist in price:
       prices = pricelist.findAll('span')[2]
       print(prices)
           for divs in prices:
               div = divs.findAll('div')[1]
               print(div)
```

На выводе ожидаю:

```
<span><div class="column-title">avg</div><div>1.24$</div></span>
<div>1.24$</div>
```

но получаю:

```
<span><div class="column-title">avg</div><div>1.24$</div></span>
[]
```

В чём тут проблема? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: а print(prices.text) или print(div.text) - не оно?

Comment: @Jack_oS мне нужно взять из prices второй div, а оттуда уже div.text, а prices.text вернёт мне строку, из которой потом будет сложно искать число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы написали лишний for, поэтому ничего и не работает, а вот так должно

```
for pricelist in price:
   prices = pricelist.findAll('span')[2]
   print(prices)
   div = prices.findAll('div')[1]
   print(div)
```